# cannot get nearest column value using Match in excel

Tags: excel

I want to get the nearest column value . For Example: there are two columns, 50,40   . When the input will be 45, it will select column number under 40, but it selects column under 50. I have used -1 for descending order of match function .

Here is the table:
[image]

Anyone know how to get the nearest column in Excel ?

Comment: What value are you looking to return for say values of 49, 45 and 41?  Is the lookup array always linear in steps of 10?

Comment: If the value is 41,42,...,48,49 . Then it would return column 2 as it falls under the range of 40-49

Answer (score 1):

To get **nearest** match use this array formula

`=MATCH(MIN(ABS(C3-A1:E1)),ABS(C3-A1:E1),0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That works whatever the order of `A1:E1`

If you want to match with greatest value <= to C3 try this version

`=MATCH(MAX(IF(A1:E1<C3,A1:E1)),A1:E1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, when using -1

> MATCH finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to
>   lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed
>   in descending order, for example: TRUE, FALSE, Z-A, ...2, 1, 0, -1,
>   -2, ..., and so on.

**EDIT**

```
=COUNTIF(A1:E1,">"&C3)+1
```

:)

Comment: It would be nice if someone could provide solution to above problem without sorting and keeping the table same.

Comment: Was too focused on using MATCH!

Answer (score 0):

The function you used returns the following: 1=less than, 0=equals, and -1=greater than.  So, returning 1 is correct as only one value is greater than 49.